# MySql database help for a plugin

Tags: plugins, mysql

I am using a WordPress plugin called [MyReview](http://www.myreviewplugin.com/) but I want some changes to it.

That plugin has feature to review posts, where users will come and give star ratings to the post according to categories, but in that plugin a user can give star rating to a post to as many times as the user wants, which I dont want, what I want is a user can give star rating to a post just a single time, for that purpose I had words with the author of the plugin, and he suggested me something like this,

> Query the comments table for any
>   comments by the same email ID, check
>   if there are any attached ratings, if
>   there are, don't accept the ratings.
>   All these changes would go in
>   myrp-save.php. If you know PHP and are
>   comfortable working with phpMyAdmin to
>   understand the database tables, it
>   would not be difficult to do.

```
SELECT id FROM myrp_ratings as rat, wp_comments as com WHERE com.comment_ID=rat.comment_id AND com.comment_author_email='whatever@whatever.com' AND rat.value!='0' AND rat.value!='1' LIMIT 1
```

How can I put this line in that plugin file which is `myrp-save.php`?  I think code should be inserted after this line or before this line:

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `" . $wpdb->myrp_ratings . "`(`ID`, `category_id`, `post_id`, `comment_id`, `value`, `outof`, `weighted`) VALUES('', '{$name}', '{$postID}', '-1', '{$value}', '{$outof}', '" . ($value/$outof) . "')");
```

How can this be done?

```
<?php

    function myrp_save_comment_fields($commentID)
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $fields = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " .$wpdb->myrp_comment_fields." ORDER BY `order`");

        $rq = get_option("myrp_comment_fields_required");
        foreach($fields as $f)
        {
            $puniqid = str_replace(".", "_", $f->uniqid);
            if(!isset($_POST[$puniqid])) continue;
            $postdata = $_POST[$puniqid];

            switch($f->type)
            {
                case "date":
                    if(strlen($postdata) > 2)
                    {
                        $date = strtotime($postdata);
                        if($date > strtotime($f->minimum))
                        {
                            add_comment_meta($commentID, $f->uniqid, $date, true)
                                or
                            update_comment_meta($commentID, $f->uniqid, $date);
                        } else {
                            if($rq)
                            {
                                wp_die(__("Field {$f->name} is required and must be after {$f->minimum}!", "myrp") . " <a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Click here to continue...</a>");
                            } else {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                break;


                case "short": case "long":
                    if(strlen($postdata) > 0)
                    {
                        $text = ($postdata);
                        if(strlen($text) > intval($f->minimum) && strlen($text) < $f->maximum)
                        {
                            add_comment_meta($commentID, $f->uniqid, $text, true)
                                or
                            update_comment_meta($commentID, $f->uniqid, $text);
                        } else {
                            if($rq)
                            {
                                wp_die(__("Field {$f->name} is required and must be between {$f->minimum} and {$f->maximum} characters!", "myrp") . " <a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Click here to continue...</a>");
                            } else {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                break;

                case "number":
                    if(strlen($postdata) > 0)
                    {
                        $text = intval($postdata);
                        if(($text) > intval($f->minimum) && strlen($text) < $f->maximum)
                        {
                            add_comment_meta($commentID, $f->uniqid, $text, true)
                                or
                            update_comment_meta($commentID, $f->uniqid, $text);
                        } else {
                            if($rq)
                            {
                                wp_die(__("Field {$f->name} is required and must be between {$f->minimum} and {$f->maximum}!", "myrp") . " <a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Click here to continue...</a>");
                            } else {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                break;

                case "select": case "radio": case "check":
                    if(strlen($postdata) > 0)
                    {
                            add_comment_meta($commentID, $f->uniqid, $postdata, true)
                                or
                            update_comment_meta($commentID, $f->uniqid, $postdata);
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

// myrp_require_rating_comment, myrp_require_all_rating_comment
    function myrp_save_ratings($commentID) 
    {
        global $wpdb; global $myrp_type_outof;
        $post_id = $_POST['comment_post_ID'];
        $rating_categories = get_post_meta($post_id, "_myrp_rating_categories", true);

        if(is_array($rating_categories) && count($rating_categories) > 0)
        {
            $submit_count = 0;
            foreach($rating_categories as $rc)
            {
                $type = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT `type` FROM `" . $wpdb->myrp_categories . "` WHERE `ID`='{$rc}' LIMIT 1");
                $outof = $myrp_type_outof[$type];

                if(isset($_POST[$rc . "_input"]) && $_POST[$rc."_input"] != "")
                {
                    $submit_count++;
                    $value = $_POST[$rc . "_input"];


                        if(!empty($value))
                        {
                            if($value < 1) $value = 1;
                            if($value > $outof) $value = $outof;
                            $value = round($value*2)/2;
                        } else {
                            $value = 0;
                        }

                    $sql =<<< SQL
SELECT
  id
FROM
  myrp_ratings AS rat,
  wp_comments AS com
WHERE 1=1
  AND com.comment_ID = rat.comment_id
  AND com.comment_author_email = '%s'
  AND rat.value != '0'
  AND rat.value != '1'
LIMIT
 1
SQL;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,'whatever@whatever.com');
$id = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
                    if (is_null($id)) {
  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `" . $wpdb->myrp_ratings . "`(`ID`, `category_id`, `post_id`, `comment_id`, `value`, `outof`, `weighted`) VALUES('', '{$name}', '{$postID}', '-1', '{$value}', '{$outof}', '" . ($value/$outof) . "')");    
}
                }
            }


            if(
                (
                    get_post_meta($post_id, "_myrp_no_allow_comments_without_ratings", true) == 1 && $submit_count == 0
                )
                    ||
                (
                    (
                        (get_option("myrp_require_rating_comment") == 1 && $submit_count == 0)
                            ||
                        (get_option("myrp_require_all_rating_comment") == 1 && $submit_count != count($rating_categories))
                    )
                        &&
                    (
                        get_post_meta($post_id, "_myrp_allow_comments_without_ratings", true) != 1
                    )
                )
            ) {
                //$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `".$wpdb->myrp_ratings."` WHERE `comment_id`='{$commentID}' LIMIT {$submit_count}");
                wp_delete_comment($commentID);  // should clean up ratings on its own.
                wp_die(__("Ratings are required! Please select star ratings for this review.", "myrp") . " <a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Click here to continue...</a>");
            }

        }
        if(get_post_meta($post_id, "_myrp_automatically_approve_comments", true) == 1) $wpdb->query("UPDATE `" . $wpdb->comments . "` SET `comment_approved`=1 WHERE comment_ID='{$commentID}' AND `comment_approved`=0");
        wp_update_comment_count($post_id);
        do_action("myrp-savingratings");
        update_option("myrp_notChanged",0);

        return true;
    }

    function myrp_save_post($postID) 
    {
        global $wpdb;
        global $myrp_type_outof;

        myrp_save_hides($postID);
        if(isset($_POST['myrp_affiliate_link'])) {
            $affiliate_link = trim($_POST['myrp_affiliate_link']);
            if(!empty($affiliate_link))
            {
                $link = parse_url($affiliate_link);
                $scheme = $link['scheme'];
                if($scheme == "")  $affiliate_link = "http://" . $affiliate_link;
            }

            add_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_affiliate_link", $affiliate_link, true)
                or 
            update_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_affiliate_link",$affiliate_link);
        }

        if(isset($_POST['myrp_icon_image'])) {
            $icon_image = $_POST['myrp_icon_image'];
            if(!empty($icon_image))
            {
                $link = parse_url($icon_image);
                $scheme = $link['scheme'];
                if($scheme == "")  $icon_image = "http://" . $icon_image;
            }

            add_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_icon_image",$icon_image, true)
                or 
            update_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_icon_image", $icon_image);
        }

        $checked = array();
        $rating_categories = array();
        if(isset($_POST['myrp_save_categories_please']))
        {
            if(count($_POST['myrp_checked_categories']) > 0)
            {
                foreach($_POST['myrp_checked_categories'] as $cid)
                {
                    if(@$_POST["myrp_value_" . $cid] != "")
                    {
                        $rating = (@$_POST["myrp_value_" . $cid]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $rating = "";
                    }


                    $checked[] = array($cid, $rating);
                    $rating_categories[] = $cid;
                }
            }
            add_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_rating_categories", $rating_categories, true)
                or
            update_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_rating_categories", $rating_categories);


            if(count($rating_categories) > 0)
            {
                update_option("myrp_previously_checked", $rating_categories);
            } else {
                update_option("myrp_previously_checked", array());
            }

            $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `" . $wpdb->myrp_ratings . "` WHERE `post_id`='{$postID}' AND `comment_id`='-1'");

            foreach($checked as $rating) 
            {
                $name = $rating[0];
                $value = $rating[1];

                $type = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT `type` FROM `" . $wpdb->myrp_categories . "` WHERE `ID`='{$name}' LIMIT 1");
                $outof = $myrp_type_outof[$type];

                if($outof == 1)
                {
                    if($value == "Yes") $value = 1;
                    if($value == "No") $value = 0;
                }

                if($outof == 40)
                {

                    $value = myrp_translate_letter_to_number($value);

                }
                $value = floatval($value);

                $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `" . $wpdb->myrp_ratings . "`(`ID`, `category_id`, `post_id`, `comment_id`, `value`, `outof`, `weighted`) VALUES('', '{$name}', '{$postID}', '-1', '{$value}', '{$outof}', '" . ($value/$outof) . "')");
            }
        }


        update_option("myrp_notChanged",0);

    }

    function myrp_save_hides($postID)
    {

        if(isset($_POST['_myrp_hide_set']))
        {
            add_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_hide_float_left", $_POST['_myrp_hide_float_left'], true)
                or
            update_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_hide_float_left",$_POST['_myrp_hide_float_left']);

            add_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_hide_float_right", $_POST['_myrp_hide_float_right'], true)
                or
            update_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_hide_float_right",$_POST['_myrp_hide_float_right']);

            add_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_disable_traffic_tracking", $_POST['_myrp_disable_traffic_tracking'], true)
                or
            update_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_disable_traffic_tracking",$_POST['_myrp_disable_traffic_tracking']);

            add_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_disable_advanced_excerpts", $_POST['_myrp_disable_advanced_excerpts'], true)
                or
            update_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_disable_advanced_excerpts",$_POST['_myrp_disable_advanced_excerpts']);

            add_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_hide_microformats", $_POST['_myrp_hide_microformats'], true)
                or
            update_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_hide_microformats",$_POST['_myrp_hide_microformats']);

            add_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_allow_comments_without_ratings", $_POST['_myrp_allow_comments_without_ratings'], true)
                or
            update_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_allow_comments_without_ratings",$_POST['_myrp_allow_comments_without_ratings']);

            add_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_automatically_approve_comments", $_POST['_myrp_automatically_approve_comments'], true)
                or
            update_post_meta($postID, "_myrp_automatically_approve_comments",$_POST['_myrp_automatically_approve_comments']);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Considering you're using a premium plug-in, have you thought to just contact the person you bought it from and ask for the changes?  Even the single site license comes with "lifetime technical support."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@ntechi:**

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$sql =<<< SQL
SELECT
  id
FROM
  myrp_ratings AS rat,
  INNER JOIN wp_comments AS com ON com.comment_ID = rat.comment_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND com.comment_author_email = '%s'
  AND rat.value != '0'
  AND rat.value != '1'
LIMIT
 1
SQL;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,'whatever@whatever.com');
$id = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
if (is_null($id)) {
  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `" . $wpdb->myrp_ratings . "`(`ID`, `category_id`, `post_id`, `comment_id`, `value`, `outof`, `weighted`) VALUES('', '{$name}', '{$postID}', '-1', '{$value}', '{$outof}', '" . ($value/$outof) . "')");    
}
```

Note how I formatted the SQL so you could actually read it? *(though admittedly I didn't go to the effort with the `INSERT`.)*  Also, note how I used `$wpdb->prepare()` to ensure that no SQL injection attacks were used from invalid email addresses? *(Your plugin developer unfortunately did not do the same.)*

Also be careful modifying plugins; if you do you need to change the version number to something huge like 999 to ensure you or another user doesn't accidentally overwrite your changes when the vendor updates their plugin. Best if possible to get them to incorporate your changes into the next release of their plugin.

Comment: hey i ll try this, but the plugin is this http://www.myreviewplugin.com/

you edited wrong plugin, thanks anyway i ll try and let you know

Comment: @ntechi - *"Edited wrong plugin?"*  You mean I linked to the wrong plugin? If yes, see what happens when you don't include the hyperlinks yourself? ;-)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel♦ - i tried the code but when a user comes to give comment and rating for the first time, the rating is not coming, what i want is, first time when the user comes and gives comment and rating, both should come, when the user comes second time, and even if he tries to give rating, then also just comment should come not rating, the code which you provided, in that only comment is coming not rating

Comment: @ntechi - _"the rating is not coming"_  What does that mean?  Since you did not post any of the context around the SQL query I cannot tell what you are doing wrong. Please post the entire function you are modifying as an update to your question or I can't help. Or do what @EAMann suggestion and ask the vendor for support. You can show him my answer and maybe it will make it quicker for them to help you?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel♦ - i ll paste the entire code, here, and the rating not coming means, the star rating the user gives,

and yes i copy pasted the code, i am weak in Mysql thats why, sorry for that,
check my original answe

Comment: @ntechi - The SQL in this question is incidental. The SQL just does a query to see if there is a comment for the user. `$id` should either be a numeric value or null. You know how to do to a `print_r()`, right? Do a `print_r($wpdb);` right after the `get_var()` and look for error messages. *(I'm assuming the SQL is correct based on what the vendor gave. Maybe the SQL is wrong but I can't tell since I don't have access to the commercial plugin.)*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel♦- i types `print_r($wpdb)` as you mentioned, but i am not getting errors, just now the star ratings are not coming for any comment, and the author of the plugin is also not responding to me, he is not helping me, if you want i can email you the copy of this plugin, so that you ll come to know how the plugin functions

Comment: @MikeSchinkel♦ - i think the sql query should be some like this,
let the sql query check, if the email id is new for this post then run the insert query else do nothing, i dont know much about mysql just a try, what will be the mysql query for this?

Comment: @ntechi - I don't know what the correct SQL is because I don't have access to the database structures for the plugin nor do I have the plugin to test with. I used the SQL query you posted that came from the email of the plugin developer. You'll need to provide more information as already requested or I cannot help you any more *(except I'm going to make a small change to the SQL for you to try, but I doubt it will fix it if the current version is not working.)* If you want more help you need to post the database structures and/or get the vendor to provide me a copy of the plugin.

Comment: @ntechi - Try to change I made. If that doesn't work post a zipped copy of the database, and all your scripts so I can download and test w/o having to spend lots of time getting it set up. Email me a URL.

Comment: i am giving you the plugin copy, the vendor is not responding me from last 2 months, i can email you the copy if you want

give me your mail ID

Comment: @ntechi - See my profile.

Comment: i am not getting you, wat to see in your profile?

Comment: @ntechi - My email address.

Comment: i have emailed you